# Build executable .jar with external .jar dependencies copied in a lib folder

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ IDEA and Java. I have my main program, named `SearchEngine` which should build an executable `SearchEngine.jar`. However, there are dependencies in my code to 3 extra .jar files. I have added those dependencies and my program is working fine.

I want to build an executable .jar that does **not** include the 3 extra .jar files inside it, but instead, it copies them in a `lib` folder. For that matter I selected the following option:

[image: 1]

When I don't change the settings in the *Artifacts* project settings tab, I get 4 .jar files, 1 of which is my executable and 3 are the extra .jar files. This way, everything **works** fine.

[image: 2]

However, when I try and add the 3 extra .jar files inside a `lib` folder, my executable does **not work**, even though the 3 extra .jars are getting copied in a `lib` folder. How to make this work ?

[image: 3]

Comment: Are you using maven? It can manage dependencies and package them in a jar.

Comment: @jiggy I am not trying to package the dependencies in a .jar, please read the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Manually editing the `MANIFEST.MF` file like below (adding `libs/` in front of every .jar name), fixed it.

Before:

```
Class-Path: lucene-core-4.10.2.jar lucene-queryparser-4.10.2.jar lucen
 e-analyzers-common-4.10.2.jar
```

After:

```
Class-Path: libs/lucene-core-4.10.2.jar libs/lucene-queryparser-4.10.2.jar
 libs/lucene-analyzers-common-4.10.2.jar
```